# How can I keep updating my ListBox synchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, ienumerable

I am calculating prime numbers bw two numbers using following code

```
 private static IEnumerable<int> GetPrimes(int from, int to)
    {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
        {
            bool isPrime = true;
            int limit = (int)Math.Sqrt(i);
            for (int j = 2; j <= limit; j++)
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (isPrime)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }       
    }
```

And I want to update my list box without blocking my UI thread, with all the prime numbers using above code. The approch which I am using as following but this is not working out.

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.DoWork += _worker_DoWork;
        this.DataContext = this;

    } 

  private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        PrimeNumbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        foreach (var item in GetPrimes(1, 10000000))
        {               
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(Test), item);
        }            
    }

    private void Test(int obj)
    {
        PrimeNumbers.Add(obj);
    }

 public ObservableCollection<int> PrimeNumbers 
    {
        get
        {
            return primeNumbers;
        }
        set
        {
            primeNumbers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PrimeNumbers");

        }
    }

 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

but this approach freezes my UI. I want to have result continuously coming from the GetPrimes method and keep adding to my listboz

Comment: You could just do all the work on the worker thread, and then do an Invoke() on the control with all the updated info.
Or you can do the same with the code you have, since you want to update it regularly, just get all the numbers first, and then do the begininvoke, instead of doing it for every number,

Comment: Simple. You are updating the UI very frequently. Amount of work done in worker thread is comparatively less than what UI thread does. You could update all at once or do it in a batch.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks a lot. You helped me get to the solution which I will put as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just posting too much. This code works as expected:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> PrimeNumbers { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PrimeNumbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPrimes(PrimeNumbers.Add, 1, 10000000, SynchronizationContext.Current);
    }

    private static void PrintPrimes(Action<int> action, int from, int to, 
                                    SynchronizationContext syncContext)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (var i = from; i <= to; i++)
            {
                var isPrime = true;
                var limit = (int) Math.Sqrt(i);
                for (var j = 2; j <= limit; j++)
                {
                    if (i%j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    syncContext.Post(state => action((int)state), i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Consider avoiding old BackgroundWorker class. Also, instead of using a synchronization mechanism of your platform try to switch to platform independent SynchronizationContext.

Instead of sleeping a thread you can post your results in bunches:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> PrimeNumbers { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PrimeNumbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPrimes(items => items.ForEach(PrimeNumbers.Add), 
                    1, 10000000, SynchronizationContext.Current);
    }

    private static void PrintPrimes(Action<List<int>> action, int from, int to, 
                                    SynchronizationContext syncContext)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var primesBuffer = new List<int>();
            for (var i = from; i <= to; i++)
            {
                var isPrime = true;
                var limit = (int) Math.Sqrt(i);
                for (var j = 2; j <= limit; j++)
                {
                    if (i%j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    primesBuffer.Add(i);
                    if (primesBuffer.Count >= 1000)
                    {
                        syncContext.Post(state => action((List<int>) state), 
                                         primesBuffer.ToList());
                        primesBuffer.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can use `Thread` instead of `Task.Run` if you're stuck with older versions of a framework.

Comment: I think you don't need a `_locker` and `lock (_locker)` at all. Otherwise this answer is good +1

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, lock is definitely needed here as `Add` is not thread-safe. I've checked it and I get an exception if lock is not presented.

Comment: No, you don't need it. because only one thread will be calling it (UI thread). So, why do you need to lock it? If you get an exception that's probably due to some other reason. I think before you didn't have `primesBuffer.ToList()`, if that's true, you'll get exception.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, yes, you are right, I've got an exception when I've been messing with my code, so I decided to add a lock, but your reasoning is completely correct, I've fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks ok, you just forgot to *start* your background worker by calling [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
PrimeNumbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
```

This line needs to be outside your worker (or being invoked in the UI thread as well).

Comment: If he doesn't start the worker the how does it freezes the UI?

Comment: Start is there, i just missed to mention here. After starting the UI freezes.

Comment: Well, you are updating *a lot* so it could well be that it looks like the UI froze. That said, if start is there, could you please post your *real* code?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like my UI was getting upadated very frequently so I have used a delay of 1 second on my background worker thread. It helped me to achieve my functionality

private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

```
        foreach (var item in GetPrimes(1, 1000000))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(Test), item);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: No please. Don't do that. Why are you putting a thread in sleep state for no reason.? Your best bet will be to update the UI in batch. Say every 10000 elements.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am not sure, how to do that. Can you please give me some reference code. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Vikram, you can see an implementation in my second code example.

Comment: Yes, I recommend @aush answer. Second part of his answer shows it.